# querySelector not working on IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, selectors-api

Here is my code. Could someone tell what's wrong ?

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document; //working
var y = x.querySelector('.myClass'); // not working
```

I can't use JQuery. 
I've also tried with :

```
var y = x.querySelectorAll('myClass')
var y = x.querySelectorAll('.myClass')
var y = x.querySelectorAll('[class=myClass]')
var y = x.querySelectorAll('[class="myClass"]')
```

I got : "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: In IE8 it was possible to run documents in an iframe in different document mode than the main page. Make sure the iframe document is also run in IE8 mode.

Comment: How can I check if the iframe document is also run in IE8 mode ? The two option that I know are compatibility document mode and compatibility browser mode. Both are set to IE8

Comment: Peek the file, if there's a proper DTD at the top of the file (i.e. on the first line), everything should be fine. Or are you emulating IE8 with  a newer IE?

Comment: <!-- DOCTYPE html --> is that what you meant ?

Comment: No, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. What you have is a comment.

Comment: Sorry it actually is <!DOCTYPE html> so what's wrong :( ? The method does work for other classes tags (I ckecked it) but not in this case. I'm pretty sure it have something to do with the fact that it is in a IFRAME.